# How do I know what kind of coating is on this pan?

Tags: equipment, pan, non-stick, aluminum-cookware

My family bought a pan in France. There is very little information about this pan (it's a Monoprix brand), but the label attached to the pan says that the pan's material is aluminum and the coating is "Anti-stick Whitford". The pan itself looks like this:
[image: a photo of the pan's coating]

And the label is like this:

[image: pan's label]

After some online searching, it appears that "Whitford" is actually a company, not a coating type, and that company makes several kinds of non-stick pan coating. Is there some way to determine which one was used in this specific pan?

It might also be the case that "Whitford" is a common name for some specific coating type in France (where the pan was bought) or in Italy (where it was made). Then what coating is that?

Comment: Translation:
Do not use certain detergents corrosives or abrasive sponges. Avoid thermal shocks. Do not allow the background flame to protrude at the risk of heating the handles. For your safety and that of your children, never allow food to heat up without supervision or within the reach of a child. Turn the handle towards the inside of your cooktop. Use a lid to avoid any risk of projection and burns. Use gloves when handling this utensil. 

Body and bottom: Aluminum  Coating: Whitford Non-Stick PFOA-free*
Bakelite handle
*Polyetrafluoroethylene

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Whitford](https://www.coatingsworld.com/contents/view_breaking-news/2016-06-02/all-whitford-nonstick-coatings-available-without-pfoa/) is, in fact, a chemical company that makes nonstick coatings, so the label makes sense.  Since 2016 they've been offering PTFE (Teflon) without PFOA, so that's most likely what the coating on the pan is.  While Whitford does make [more exotic coatings](https://orioncoat.com/specification-by-supplier/ppgwhitford-xylan-non-stick-coatings/), it's not clear than any of them are used in cookware, and your pan certainly looks like regular PTFE.

Whitford also has brand names around specific coatings like [Eterna](https://www.microsurfacecorp.com/eterna.php), but that's just a specific application of PTFE.

So what you have is Teflon.  Enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

I think this means that the Whitford company has a "house recipe" for a pan coating that is not teflon-based ("Sans PFOA" means without a helper chemical that was used in teflon production, but has been banned in the EU).

It is probably next to impossible to determine what kind of coating exactly was used on this pan, although with the EU's strict regulations on food safety I would not worry about adverse effects and just exercise the regular caution for coated pans.

Comment: Modern "Teflon" is made without PFOA, but it's still basically the same thing.